# How To Write Test Code Account Trigger Handler After Update

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, after-trigger

I wrote a trigger handler class on account to send an email if the code red field changes. If the code red field changes from true to false the email is sent and it blanks out certain fields on account. The code is working fine. The test code works fine as well and it gives me 90% coverage but once I add assertions the code fails. Below is a simplified version of my code

Trigger

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        if(AccountHandler.isFirstTime)
        {
            AccountHandler.isFirstTime = false;
            for (Account a: Trigger.New) 
            {
                Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.ID);
                if (a.AM_Code_Red__c!= oldAccount.AM_Code_Red__c)
                {
                    AccountHandler.codeRedIn(Trigger.new, Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
                }
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Handler

```
public class AccountHandler {
public static Boolean isFirstTime = true;
public static void codeRedIn(List<Account> listOfNewAccounts, List<Account> listOfOldAccounts, Map <Id, Account> acc)
{
    String body = 'Test';
    String adresses = '123@test.com';
    for (Account a: listOfNewAccounts) 
    {
        List<ID> AccID = New List<ID>();
        Account oldAccount = acc.get(a.ID);
        EmailManager em = new EmailManager();
        em.sendMail(adresses, 'Automated Alert: Updated Code Red Account- ' + a.Name, body);
        body ='';

        if (oldAccount.AM_Code_Red__c == true && a.AM_Code_Red__c == false)
        {
            AccID.add(a.Id);
            codeRedOut(AccID);
        }
    }
}
public static void codeRedOut(List<ID> AccID){
    system.debug('AccountHandler - Code Red Out');
    Map<Id, Account> updates = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(Id accountId: AccID) {
    updates.put(accountId, 
                new Account(
                    Id=accountId, 
                    Date_Time_Code_Red_Exit__c = System.now(),
                    Risk_of_Churn__c = '',
                    Churn_Stage__c = '',
                    What_percent_at_risk__c = '')
               );
    }
    system.debug('Updates- '+ updates);
    update updates.values();            
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class AccountTest {
    @isTest static void TestCodeRedIn(){  
    // Test data setup
    Account acc = TestDataFactory.InsertAccount();
    AccountHandler.isFirstTime = true;

    Account accountToUpdate = [select Id, Risk_of_Churn__c from Account where Id = :acc.Id];
    system.debug(accountToUpdate);
    if(accountToUpdate.Id != null) 
    {
        accountToUpdate.AM_Code_Red__c = true;
        accountToUpdate.Churn_Stage__c = 'Verbal Intent';
    }
    system.debug(accountToUpdate);
    // Perform test
    Test.startTest();             
    update accountToUpdate;
    system.debug(accountToUpdate);
    AccountHandler.isFirstTime = true;
    accountToUpdate.AM_Code_Red__c = false;
    update accountToUpdate;
    system.debug(accountToUpdate);
    Account codeRedOut = [select Id, AM_Code_Red__c, Risk_of_Churn__c from Account where Id = :acc.Id];
    system.debug(codeRedOut);

    Test.stopTest();
    // Verify Data
    System.assert(accountToUpdate.AM_Code_Red__c==true);
    System.assert(accountToUpdate.Risk_of_Churn__c == '');
    }
    @isTest static void TestCodeRedOut(){  
        AccountHandler.isFirstTime = true;
        Account acc = TestDataFactory.InsertCodeRedAccount();
       
        Account accountToUpdate = [select Id, AM_Code_Red__c, Risk_of_Churn__c from Account where Id = :acc.Id];
        system.debug(accountToUpdate);
        if(accountToUpdate.Id != null) {
            accountToUpdate.AM_Code_Red__c = false;
        }
        system.debug(accountToUpdate);
        // Perform test
        Test.startTest();             
        update accountToUpdate;
        AccountHandler.isFirstTime = true;
        system.debug(accountToUpdate);
        Account codeRedOut = [Select Id, AM_Code_Red__c, Date_Time_Code_Red_Exit__c, Risk_of_Churn__c, Churn_Stage__c, What_percent_at_risk__c From Account Where Id = : accountToUpdate.Id ];
        system.debug(codeRedOut);       
        Test.stopTest();
        // Verify Data
        System.assert(codeRedOut.AM_Code_Red__c==false);
        System.assert(codeRedOut.Risk_of_Churn__c == '');
    }
}
```

The first assert passes but the second one fails. I think the problem has to do with the AccountHandler.isFirstTime. How do I get the test to pass without removing isFirstTime and risk running into a loop?

Comment: You are trying to do too many things in the test. Try to assert what you expect to happen after the first update. That'll help you to detect what's wrong. Also, I wouldn't check if(accountToUpdate.Id != null) --> if you're creating the record on test code, it shouldn't be null, and if it's null, it means that you're not inserting it correctly

Comment: @AlbaRivas - Initially I had two separate methods to test coderedin and coderedout but it still wasn't working. Here's the method I originally had in the test class

Comment: Then you have to debug more. Are you sure that the test record is being created? I'd remove if(accountToUpdate.Id != null) and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the last assert to
`System.assertEquals(codeRedOut.Risk_of_Churn__c , null);` seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks for your help.